# How to get the Username and Password in the service side of a WCF call?

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-security

When I supply credentials at client with following code:

```
myChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
myChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "password";
```

Then on server side I see that these credentials are available in

```
operationContext.IncomingMessageHeaders[1]
```

However is there any more convenenient method to get the UserName and password? All I see in [`OperationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is chaos of properties and untyped lists and I cant find anything that indicates where I can get this.

Comment: Why do you want this? Are you trying to perform additional authentication?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the static [`Current` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicesecuritycontext.current.aspx) on the [`ServiceSecurityContext` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicesecuritycontext.aspx) to get the current `ServiceSecurityContext` for the operation that is being called.

You can then use the [`PrimaryIdentity` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicesecuritycontext.primaryidentity.aspx) in order to get the identity of the user with the credentials passed in.

However, it will not (nor should it), expose the password.  If you truly need the password, then you will have to drop down to the message level and inspect the headers, as you've seen.

Comment: No this is something else. In SecurityCServiceContext contains users WINDOWS CREDENTIALS. That is something totally different then credentials I set on channel factory.

Comment: @Kalaz: No, that's not true, the WindowsIdentity property gives you WINDOWS CREDENTIALS.  PrimaryIdentity is something else completely.

Answer (score 2):

This is entirely dependent on the binding you are using, and there is no general answer.

For example, if you use the NetNamedPipeBinding and do

```
myChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
myChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "password";
```

you are wasting your time: the client side binding will do nothing with this data, it won't be in the message, and it won't be accessible at all on the service side.

The binding will only consume this data if it is configured with security options which specify the use of username/password credentials. All the standard bindings which do so will use the credentials for authentication, the results of which will then surface in the service via the `ServiceSecurityContext` as casperOne indicated, and won't include the Password data.

In order to support authentication, the data must be carried somewhere in the message headers. Exactly where and in what form will again be binding-dependent. Don't assume that you'll always find them in `operationContext.IncomingMessageHeaders[1]`.

EDIT:
You may be able to construct a custom binding which gives you what you are looking for.

```
CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding( ... );
binding.Elements.Insert(1, 
  SecurityBindingElement.CreateUserNameOverTransportBindingElement());
```

On the service side, provide a `UserNamePasswordValidator` and configure the credentials like this:

```
serviceHost.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.UserNamePasswordValidationMode = 
  System.ServiceModel.Security.UserNamePasswordValidationMode.Custom;
servicehost.Credentials.UserNameAuthentication.CustomUserNamePasswordValidator = 
  new MyUserNamePasswordValidator();
```

The user name and password will then be delivered to the `Validate` method of `MyUserNamePasswordValidator`.

WARNING: This is not a secure authentication mechanism unless you are using a secure transport, as the credentials are sent in clear in the message header.

Comment: Hm yes true. Well can I configure custom binding so that I have both pieces of information on server side in one place in code? (username/password and information about domain credentials) I need both pieces at one place so that  I can use the one that is valid.

Comment: @Kalaz: See the edit to my answer. You can do custom username/password validation. But not sure whether this is exactly what you're looking for as you refer to domain credentials as well.

Comment: I will try your suggestion out by the end of the week. To clear the confusion about domain credentials: What I am looking for is a way to authenticate user via his membership in domain + my custom login/password. In reality I will use domain membership so that application behaves in single sign on manner. However when domain info is not available I am going to use custom credentials. If your solution yields accessible SecurityContext with domain info It will be what I am looking for.